# Spring auto inject with constructor via code or annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Given having next classes:

- XRepository with declared a constructor with 1 argument (simple one,
  not autowired), it has some autowired fields.
- XService that uses XRepository as autowired.
- XProcessor uses XService as autowired.

So I have to init XProcessor on runtime for specific value that will be used in XRepository constructor. On different calls I will have different arguments, so the injection should be on runtime.
Any idea how to achieve that using code configuration or annotations?

Comment: Ca you be more specific? Where is that 1 argument coming from? Configuration file?

Comment: No, is getting as part of url and can be changed on each request. Also can be different simultaneously for different users.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that Spring needs to inject all the constructor parameters of Spring managed beans.

I believe you have two options:

1. Parse your URL info in controller and pass it through parameters down to persistence layer. This would be my preferred mechanism. You can create special DTO for passing various information down and keep your method signatures concise.
2. Your situation can alos be solved with `request` scope bean. You will
   create one bean like this:

   ```
   @Component
   @Scope("request")
   public class {
       private String urlPart;
   }
   ```

   And you would autowire this component into `XProcessor` and
   `XRepository`. Each request to your application will create new
   instance of `XRequestContext` and you will parse your info in
   `XProcessor` and store it into `XRequestContext`.

   In `XRepository` you will use instance of `XRequestContext` to
   retrieve information you stored in `XProcessor`.

   You can read about request scope in [Spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-scopes-request). It is like 
   [ThreadLocal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) per request thread.